# Принцип работы функции complete в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как работает функция complete в javascript?

А если без JQuery? Например, проверка загрузки картинки `document.imgid.complete`?

Так теперь есть прогресс в понимании этого свойства. Как с ним работать? при document.imgid.complete он срабатывает сразу а не после полной загрузки картинки

Answer (score 3):

Свойство complete у тэга img - флаг, говорящий загружено изображение или нет. Если изображение загружено, то возвращает true, в противном случае false.

P.S. это не функция, это свойство (переменная).

Answer (score 0):

Функция complete есть в jQuery.ajax.
Функция, которая исполняется всякий раз после завершения запроса AJAX (после того, как выполнились success и error). В качестве аргументов функция принимает объект XMLHttpRequest и строку, описывающую тип запроса. Это событие Ajax.

```
function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      this; // the options for this ajax request
    }
```

Comment: мне кажется @varstring имел ввиду [свойство complete](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp)